# pyspark add dynamic column to select statement

Tags: pyspark

I have the following dataframe:

```
data = [("England","Yorkshire"), ("France","Île-de-France")]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema = ['Country','Region'])
```

[image]

And also a separate mapping dataframe that tells me the condition of a new column:

```
mapping_data = [("Capital","Country == England","London"),("Capital","Country == France","Paris")]
mapping_df = spark.createDataFrame(data=mapping_data, schema = ['ColumnName','Condition','Value'])
```

[image]

From the mapping dataframe I have successfully built up the when clause in a string format and store that as a variable called **Condition**:

```
when(df.Country == "England", "London").when(df.Country == "France", "Paris").alias("Capital")
```

My final step is to append this string into the select query so I can see the extra Capital column at the end like this:
[image]

To do that I was trying the query below:

```
df.select("*", Condition)
```

But I'm getting the following error

```
TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column:
```

How can I fix this?  And ps I want to use select and not withColumn

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have the expression built, you can evaluate the expression and use it with the `select` statement

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when

df.select('*', eval(Condition, {'when': when, 'df': df, '__builtins__': None}))
```

---

```
+-------+-------------+-------+
|Country|       Region|Capital|
+-------+-------------+-------+
|England|    Yorkshire| London|
| France|Île-de-France|  Paris|
+-------+-------------+-------+
```

Comment: Unfortunately that is not the solution I'm after as this is nice mock data, but in reality the Condition column isn't always just a simple a == b, it can be for example a contains b or any kind of string manipulation detection.
What I'm essentially looking for is a way to append the final built up condition (which I can build in a long when statement) to the select query to get the extra columns

Comment: I  would suggest improving your question to include the real scenario for which you are looking for a solution. Also do you already have the expression built in the string format and are you looking to use that with the select statement, correct?

Comment: Yes I have already built the expression in a string format called `Condition`, so I'm just looking for a way to run this
`df.select("*", Condition)` which is the same as doing the following: `df.select("*", when(df.Country == "England", "London").when(df.Country == "France", "Paris").alias("Capital"))`

Comment: got it. Check the edit.

Comment: didn't work for me, but I did end up with some luck by creating a dictionary of all the columns and conditions, and using selectExpr instead:
`df.selectExpr('*', *[f"{Condition} as {TargetColumn}" for TargetColumn, Condition in dictionary.items()])`